# Swagger Unable To Create Component in ASP.NET Zero .Net 7

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, abp

I am currently running an ABP solution in .Net. The solution can be built and executed without problem, but when it comes to Swagger page, I received an internal server error as such:

**HandlerException: Can't create component 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionProvider_e2489259-50be-454a-adec-747b2ac808ee' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionProvider_e2489259-50be-454a-adec-747b2ac808ee' is waiting for the following dependencies:

- Service 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderIsService' which was not registered.**

I had checked included libraries and extensions, and already have all related items included. May I know what step I am missing?

I also clean and rebuild solution, cleared .vs, obj and bin folder, uninstall + reinstall back dependencies and extensions.

Comment: Hi @CYC_Flexi, could you pls share your configuration in Program.cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when I update the ABP Version to 8.3
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8QZy.jpg)

Comment: This solve my problem too. In my case I upgraded ABP, ABP automapper and ABP Zero Common to 8.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading VS from 17.9.X to 17.8.X

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just visual Studio version 17.8.6 is useful
Also , I could not downgrade it, just by uninstall and install again that would be work

download VS 17.8.6 from here

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/5bebe58c-9308-4a5b-9696-b6f84e90a32e/f06be8b3d6c196a7e86ea2507749e200bedcf76ee7a7f6ba6c864ff9d0615f17/vs_Enterprise.exe